# How to insert 'dropdownMenu' in 'rhandsontable'?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

The JavaScript library `Handsontable` has the `'dropdownMenu'` option, which allows displaying an icon in the column headers and opening a dropdown menu with various options.

I know this can be achieved using JavaScript, but my knowledge of JavaScript is practically nonexistent. How can this option be included using the [`'rhandsontable'` package](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/) in Shiny?

Comment: Potentially relevant issue opened [here](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/430)

Comment: @Ben Thank you! Indeed, it's an excellent example... the problem lies in my lack of knowledge in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried and that doesn't work. That's because **rhandsontable** includes a too old version of **handsontable**. By the way it would be very nice if someone made a **rhandsontable2** package, because it seems that **rhandsontable** is not maintained.